# Github for Windows - can push/pull with git shell - Github GUI gives error

Tags: windows, git, github

So I clone a private repo on my VPS using SSH with Git Shell. Now when I commit changes and try to push it to my VPS it says

"Sync failed: The repository doesn't seem to exist anymore. You may not have access, or it may have been deleted or renamed."

Whenever I go into Git Shell and do "git push origin master", I enter my password and it pushes it succesfully.

Why can't I do this through the Github client?

Comment: Forgot to mention that the Github client works on my Mac and doesn't work on my friend's Windows too.